# Do others need to have the same modules installed to run my code in Python?

Tags: python, module

If I use a module such as tkinter, would somebody need to have that module installed as well in order for my code to run on their machine?

Answer (score 1):

Definitely. You can use virtual environments or containers to deliver required packages or have a `requrements.txt` or similar to install the dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

`python` comes with a number of standard modules pre-installed, if the other person is running `python` (the same version of you) then he/she won't need to install anything, it will just work, that's the case of `tkinter`. But if you use external packages that you installed to run your code, for example `celery`, then he/she will need to do the same thing.

Comment: Actually on some systems tkinter come without configuration, like on Arc linux, so you might encounter a problem with it.

Comment: @HenryHarutyunyan oh, interesting, portability is truly utopical.

Answer (score 0):

If you gave your code to someone to run, they would need to download the same modules, unless you also sent the environment too. The only way I know around this is to freeze your code where you would create an executable. I've used cx_Freeze and pyInstaller and haven't had any issues but it also depends on your needs. You can find some more information through here: 
https://docs.python-guide.org/shipping/freezing/

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

In your running environment do a, this file you add to your repo
`pip freeze > requirements.txt`

When people clone your repo, they only have to do a: 
`pip install -r requirements.txt`

and they will install exactly the same pypi modules you have.

With virtualenv you can isolate a python environment to each project, with pyenv you can use different pythonversions withing the various environment also.